# Gradle Build times are extremely erratic and unproductive

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've already increased memory in the gradle build file and these are my build times with minor changes (no extra dependencies) in the app. **Sometimes the build time is 100% greater**

```
12:01:20 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 11 sec
12:01:28 PM Session 'app': running
12:01:49 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
12:36:51 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 5 sec
12:37:05 PM Session 'app': running
12:37:24 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
12:39:47 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 58 sec
12:39:51 PM Session 'app': running
12:40:10 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
1:29:28 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 14 sec
1:36:17 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 54 sec
1:36:26 PM Session 'app': running
1:36:45 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
1:43:45 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 55 sec
1:44:55 PM Session 'app': running
1:45:15 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
1:46:13 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 14 sec
1:46:37 PM Session 'app': running
1:46:56 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
1:47:26 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 12 sec
1:47:33 PM Session 'app': running
1:47:51 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
1:59:11 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 0 sec
1:59:17 PM Session 'app': running
1:59:35 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
2:23:38 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 50 sec
2:23:42 PM Session 'app': running
2:24:01 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
2:25:27 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 0 sec
2:26:37 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 1 sec
2:26:49 PM Session 'app': running
2:27:07 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
2:42:49 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 52 sec
2:42:54 PM Session 'app': running
2:43:12 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
2:48:22 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 59 sec
2:48:29 PM Session 'app': running
2:49:21 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
3:01:38 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 55 sec
3:01:44 PM Session 'app': running
3:08:49 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 50 sec
3:09:01 PM Session 'app': running
3:09:19 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
3:12:55 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 2 sec
3:13:01 PM Session 'app': running
3:13:20 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
3:15:54 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 54 sec
3:16:08 PM Session 'app': running
3:16:28 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
3:32:39 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 50 sec
3:33:12 PM Session 'app': running
3:33:30 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
3:50:46 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 3 sec
3:51:12 PM Session 'app': running
3:51:31 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
4:11:38 PM Update Info: Android Studio is ready to update.
4:12:28 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 14 sec
4:12:35 PM Session 'app': running
4:12:53 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
4:16:12 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 5 sec
4:16:37 PM Session 'app': running
4:16:56 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
4:24:38 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 26 sec
4:25:11 PM Session 'app': running
4:25:28 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
4:45:46 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 18 sec
4:45:51 PM Session 'app': running
4:46:12 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
4:56:40 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 27 sec
4:56:47 PM Session 'app': running
4:57:07 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:05:26 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 18 sec
5:05:31 PM Session 'app': running
5:05:52 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:07:50 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 9 sec
5:07:55 PM Session 'app': running
5:08:14 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:13:04 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 10 sec
5:13:10 PM Session 'app': running
5:13:29 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:17:13 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 2 sec
5:17:22 PM Session 'app': running
5:17:41 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:22:36 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 9 sec
5:22:40 PM Session 'app': running
5:22:59 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:26:18 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 7 sec
5:26:25 PM Session 'app': running
5:26:44 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:35:50 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 5 sec
5:36:05 PM Session 'app': running
5:36:24 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:42:34 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 11 sec
5:42:47 PM Session 'app': running
5:43:07 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:50:09 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 55 sec
5:50:13 PM Session 'app': running
5:50:18 PM Session 'app': error
5:50:43 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 15 sec
5:50:46 PM Session 'app': running
5:51:04 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
5:55:55 PM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 17 sec
5:56:00 PM Session 'app': running
5:56:22 PM Session 'app': debugger connected
10:29:35 AM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 24 sec
10:29:45 AM Session 'app': running
10:30:16 AM Session 'app': debugger connected
10:43:01 AM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 1 min 59 sec
10:44:00 AM Session 'app': running
10:44:15 AM Session 'app': debugger connected
10:56:17 AM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 14 sec
10:56:24 AM Session 'app': running
10:56:40 AM Session 'app': debugger connected
11:38:07 AM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 7 sec
11:38:12 AM Session 'app': running
11:38:27 AM Session 'app': debugger connected
11:53:11 AM Gradle build finished with 4 warnings(s) in 2 min 8 sec
11:53:16 AM Session 'app': running
```

Definitive way to fix this?

Comment: What are your specs on the computer? Is it at least quad core?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the illustrative example shows the mean and average time, so it doesn't matter how large the project is or the system specs, you see that sometimes building an app takes X amount of time, and sometimes it takes over X*2 , and sometimes X-Y amount of time. And the conclusion being that this is very unproductive.

Comment: You believe that your main requirement for good performance is that builds take the same amount of time each time they are run?  Gradle makes a strong effort to only run tasks if inputs to those tasks are out of date. Your "short" builds could simply be because Gradle didn't find very much to do.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr yes, with android the 15 second builds are XML changes only, but all the other builds are largely equivalent amounts of code being changed and it seems it recompiles everything if even just 1 variable is changed

Answer (score 0):

The "erratic" build times are by design as stated by @David M. Karr. If you are trying to improve performance, I would suggest starting by enabling `org.gradle.configureondemand` and `org.gradle.daemon` in your `gradle.properties` file.